# I don't see what does "even" in the piece of code do?

Tags: haskell

```
ghci> let xxs=[[1,3,5,2,3,1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,4,2,1,6,3,1,3,2,3,6]] 
ghci> [[x|x<-   xs,even x]|xs<- xxs]
[[2,2,4],[2,4,6,8],[2,4,2,6,2,6]]
```

This piece of code relates to list comprehension. But i don't see how the program goes with "even"

Comment: It filters the list such that only even numbers are retained.

Answer (score 7):

A Haskell list comprehension expression has three types of elements at the right side of the list comprehension:

1. *generators*, of the form `var <- list-expr`;
2. *filters* of the form `bool-expr`; and
3. *local definitions* of the form `let var = expr`.

The `even x` part is thus a *filter*. It means that only if the filter is satisfied, so `even x` results in `True`, that element is a candidate for the rest of the list comprehension and thus eventually result in a branch of elements added to the list.

So here the expression thus has two components:

```
[x | x <- xs, even x ]
--   \__ __/  \__ _/
--      v        v
--  generator  filter
```

we thus iterate over the elements in `xs` and then for each element check if that element is `even`, if it is, we add `x` to the result.

The above can however be written as just:

```
filter even xs
```

which basically describe what we do here: we filter a list `xs` such that the result is a list that only contains the elements of `xs` that are even.